# How to go about not getting certain data from a JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, tree-structure

First off this is a project management database I'm messing with. So I have 3 things I want to `JOIN` together a `planning_entity` and two subqueries. These subqueries get apart of a tree structure. The parts of the tree structure I want are Project, Phase, and Activity. I need the names of the Project, Phase, The Start and Finish date of the Phase, and the hours devoted to them. The problem is, is that the hours are connected with the Activity, and the dates are the Phase. When I `JOIN` these together it pulls up the end dates for the Activity when i want it to pull up `NULL` for the Phase because the Phase has not yet been finished.

Example Code :

```
SELECT  MIN(spp.Project) AS 'Project', spp2.Phase
, FORMAT(MIN(stp.actual_start), 'd', 'en-US') AS 'Actual Start', FORMAT(MIN(stp.actual_finish), 'd', 'en-US') AS 'Actual Finish'
, FORMAT(MAX(effort_actual) + MAX(effort_reserved) + MAX(effort_required) + MAX(effort_scheduled) , 'N', 'en-us') AS 'Forecast Effort'
, FORMAT((MAX(baseline_allocated_effort) + MAX(baseline_reserved_effort) + MAX(baseline_required_effort)) , 'N', 'en-us') AS 'Baseline Effort'
, FORMAT(MAX(effort_actual), 'N', 'en-us') AS 'Effort Actual'
FROM ip.planning_entity stp 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ips.father_code
        , (SELECT ips2.description 
            FROM ip.structure ips2
            WHERE depth = 5 AND ips2.structure_code = ips.father_code) AS 'Project'
        , ips.description AS 'Activity'
    FROM ip.structure ips
    WHERE ips.depth = 6) AS spp ON spp.father_code = stp.ppl_code
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ips.structure_code
        , (SELECT ips2.description 
            FROM ip.structure ips2
            WHERE depth = 6 AND ips2.structure_code = ips.father_code) AS 'Phase'
        , ips.description AS 'Activity'
    FROM ip.structure ips
    WHERE ips.depth = 7) AS spp2 ON spp2.structure_code = stp.planning_code
LEFT JOIN ip.vw_ppm_cube_fact f on f.ppl_code = stp.ppl_code
WHERE stp.ppl_code in   
     (SELECT structure_code FROM ip.portal_filter WHERE filter_code = 83686 and usage='EX')
GROUP BY spp2.Phase
```

This is currently getting me the end dates from the Activity and not the Phase, any suggestions?

Sample data 
`PLANNING_ENTITY
planning_code   actual_start    actual_finish          ppl_code
75962   2015-03-02 08:00:00.000 NULL                    75962
82469   2015-04-30 08:00:00.000 NULL                    82469
82629   2015-05-20 08:00:00.000 NULL                    82629
82825   NULL                    NULL                    82825
82854   2015-05-08 08:00:00.000 NULL                    82854
82914   2015-05-11 08:00:00.000 NULL                    82914
82943   2015-06-05 08:00:00.000 NULL                    82943
82972   2015-04-09 08:00:00.000 NULL                    82972
83001   2015-06-02 08:00:00.000 NULL                    83001
83030   2015-03-27 17:00:00.000 2015-04-20 21:55:00.000 83030
83053   2015-04-20 08:00:00.000 NULL                    83053
83085   NULL                    NULL                    83085
83114   NULL                    NULL                    83114
83192   NULL                    NULL                    83192
83222   NULL                    NULL                    83222
83251   NULL                    NULL                    83251
83279   NULL                    NULL                    83279
83336   NULL                    NULL                    83336
83368   NULL                    NULL                    83368
83427   NULL                    NULL                    83427
83456   NULL                    NULL                    83456
83489   NULL                    NULL                    83489
83518   NULL                    NULL                    83518
85658   NULL                    NULL                    85658`

Comment: Provide sample data please...

Comment: In the question or in the comment?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide some sample data and expected result

Comment: To clarify: you are actually looking to populate the `actual_finish` column in your sample data with the end date of the phase? Have you tried a CASE statement that looks at whether the phase is complete or not?

Comment: So when I join the Phases and the Activity together it pulls in the Activity End date instead of the Phase End Date